# How to hold a CSS animation

Tags: css, reactjs

I currently am making a toast/snackbar via React and CSS. I have the snackbar opening, and closing, however, not sure what to add in order to hold the animation for a few seconds? The 'fade-in' property acts as a default state, where as 'fade-in-show' acts as the animation.

ReactJS

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

class Toaster extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ fade: true }), 100);
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ fade: false }), 3000);
  };

  state = {
    fade: false,
  };

  render() {
    const { status, children } = this.props;

    const styles = {
      box: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        right: 0,
        display: 'block',
        background: 'green',
        marginBottom: '1em',
        zIndex: 9999,
      },
      position: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        top: '18%',
        paddingLeft: '10px',
      },
    };
    if (children) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div
            style={styles.box}
            id={this.state.fade ? 'fade-in-show' : 'fade-in'}
          >
            <div style={styles.position}>{children}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

export default Toaster;
```

CSS

```
#fade-in {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2.2s ease;
}

#fade-in-show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  transition: all 2.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as CSS goes you can delay the `transition` property by adding a delay value before the duration value. Here's an example if you wanted to delay for five seconds...

`transition: all 5s 2.2s ease`